# Angular Material Stepper With Mat-Select implementing default value

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-template-form

I would like to have a default value shown with a mat-select in a stepper from Angular material.

[Edit] you cannot use formControlName with two-way binding. I ended up initializing the value in the component when declaring the form group

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true" #stepper="matHorizontalStepper">
  <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select [(value)]="actionOnFailure" formControlName="firstCtrl">
           <mat-option value="CONTINUE">CONTINUE</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="TERMINATE_ON_ANY">TERMINATE_ON_ANY</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </form> 
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

TS File

```
this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
  firstCtrl: ['INITIALIZE_VALUE_HERE', Validators.required]
});
actionOnFailure = 'Default Value'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use 2 way binding combined with a form control.  Use either Template form with 2 way binding, or the form control with a reactive form.

Remove `[(value)]="actionOnFailure"`

Then change the formcontrol to have a default value:

```
this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    firstCtrl: ['Default Value', Validators.required]
});
```

Comment: What if it is dynamic content (like using an ngFor on a form). @MDave

Comment: You can dynamically create a list of form controls with FormArray pretty easily.  Here's an example: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArrayName#example